# Estimated website clicks via Facebook Ad Manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads

I'm setting up a Facebook ad for website clicks.

The campaign shows me estimated reach for Facebook and Instagram, but it doesn't show me the estimated website clicks.

Is it possible to get a website click estimate before making the ad live?